# Is there a way to "tail -f" output of a cell in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

if I have a simple script such as this:

`for i in range(100):
    sleep(1)
    print(i)`

Is there a way to only show the last 5 lines of the output, similar to a "tail -f" command?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that works for me, I've also realized that I needed the process to work in the background.

I first had to enable widgets:
***jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension***

```
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import Label
from time import sleep

import threading

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, nloops=2000):
        self.nloops = nloops
        self.pb = Label(description='Thread loops', value="0")

    def start(self):
        display(self.pb)
        for i in range(10):
            self.pb.value += str(i) 
            sleep(1)

app = App(nloops=20000)

t = threading.Thread(target=app.start)

t.start()
```